# Unable to install a python package in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, python

I'm trying to install the reddit source code onto ubuntu 12.04.5. I'm at the point where I'm trying to install the python module dependencies from the github guide:

```
$ cd reddit/r2
$ python setup.py build
$ sudo python setup.py develop
$ make
```

But when I type `python setup.py build` into the terminal, I receive the following:

```
Cannot find Baseplate. Skipping Thrift build.
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
```

Initially I also received `Cannot find Cython. Skipping Cython build.` but I was able to fix it through a simple `sudo apt-get install cython.` But when I try `sudo apt-get install baseplate` the terminal tells me `E: Unable to locate package baseplate`.

I've tried `sudo apt-get install python-gevent python-baseplate` with no success either. I've already done a `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get update.` Nothing works. Please help.

Comment: Did you actually get any errors? Sometimes stuff just gets skipped and it's no big deal.

Comment: There is an Ubuntu install script. https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/reddit-install-script-for-Ubuntu Is there any reason you are not using that?

Comment: @mchid I'm still a complete noob, but when I do `$ make` I get `Makefile:41:***Makefile.py failed. aborting. Stop.` And I'm aware of the script, but I want to have this installed on my laptop and not a VM.

Comment: Actually, I see that that the install script is for 14.04. It is not necessarily for a virtual machine though and should be considered if you are using 14.04. However, I reviewed the instructions and detailed it out for you below. Go ahead and delete your existing directory and start over or it might not work. This should cover all the dependencies you need to get started.

Comment: I still receive the 'makefile:41' error. And I know the scripts not necessarily for a VM but its what was recommended so that nothing bad can happen to your actual computer. I'm simply going to run the script, I'm running into too many issues I'm not geared to deal with.

Comment: You might need to run `make clean` or `sudo make clean` before you run `make` to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Before you begin, delete the existing directory and start over.

First, you will need to install the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:reddit/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Next, install some dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql cassandra memcached rabbitmq-server haproxy stunnel python-setuptools python-dev libmemcached-dev libpq-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-imaging git-core gcc optipng jpegoptim postgresql-client make gettext nodejs node-less node-uglify
```

Now, clone the git repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/reddit/reddit.git
```

Install the python module dependencies:

```
cd reddit/r2
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py develop
make
```

[Continue with the instructions here.](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/Install-guide#postgresql)